# Bluetooth refuses to connect since update to Ubuntu Gnome 13.10

Tags: gnome, sound, 13.10, bluetooth, pulseaudio

I can no longer connect to my bluetooth speakers since since upgrading to Ubuntu Gnome 13.10 and then Gnome shell to 3.10, which never were a problem with Ubuntu Gnome 13.04.

My bluetooth-dongle seems to working fine and I can even detect and add the speakers (Creative D100) but when I try to slide the button from off to on in the bluetooth settings it just slides back to off. The "bluetooth-B" in the upper right corner is also gone.

I actually managed to connect after I added "Enable=Socket" under "[general]" /etc/bluetooth/audio.conf and the indicator on the speakers confirms the connection, but I cannot find the speakers in the audio settings even then.

I've tried to solve this for several days, reading tons of other possibly related questions here on ask ubuntu and elsewhere but am unable to find a solution. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YES! It's working again! Don't know what fixed it though:

I downgraded bluez (4.96) and pulseaudio (2.1-0) as recommended in this article: http://awesomeprogrammer.com/blog/2013/06/22/fixing-bluetooth-audio-issue-on-ubuntu-13-dot-04-based-distors/

Bluez refused to install without libudev0 so I installed it as suggested in this article:
http://www.unixmen.com/resolve-libudev0-issue-when-installing-google-chrome-in-ubuntu-13-04/

Before downgrading I checked if libudev0 alone would do the trick, but no. The downgrade broke everything totally with no selectable audio devices at all as a result.

Then I let Ubuntu search for Updates and accepted to update bluez, pulseaudio and all suggested (it was no updates in cue before the downgrade). I allowed the conf-files to be overwritten. Then I restarted pulseaudio ("sudo service pulseaudio restart" in the terminal). AND NOW IT WORKS!!!

Just want to add that I tried multiple times to uninstall and reinstall both bluez and pulseaudio before this and just about anything related to bluetooth.

Maybe someone can figure out what fixed the problem, otherwise I would suggest that anyone running into the same problems as me to do what I did step by step.